# Is there a way to ignore white space with :empty pseudo class?

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I'm trying to fix a layout quirk via CSS. I don't have direct control of the current markup being output.

The issue is that when we have a `<fieldset>` I need to add some margin to the bottom of it--*except* when the fieldset is empty--in which case I don't want an margin (as I don't want an empty fieldset taking up space).

Ideally, I could use the `:empty` pseudo class. Unfortunately, the way our markup is being generated, by "empty" fieldset ends up like this:

> ```
> <fieldset> </fieldset>
> ```

Which is no longer empty, as there is a space in the markup between the opening and closing tag.

Is there any way, via CSS, to target a fieldset with only a space text element as the child node?

Comment: Could you apply the margin to the last element in your fieldset instead?

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using `:blank`.

- `:empty` - select elements that are empty.
- `:blank` - powered-up form
  of `:empty`, lets you select even white space.

I found an [article](https://zellwk.com/blog/empty-and-blank/) that might help you understand more about the two.

**Note:** Though `:blank` is more powerful, it's not supported by all browsers.

Comment: `:blank` doesn't appear to be supported by any major browsers yet.

Comment: True, I forgot to mention that. I'll add that as a note. Thanks for bringing it up!

Comment: dang. `:blank` is exactly what I'm looking for! But...I guess that does me no good now. Maybe in 5 years! :)